# How to open current page in new window

Tags: javascript, html

What i want to do is when the user opens their browser and types http://xyz.com/index.html, then it should pop up a new full screen window and then display index page in that new window.

I tried with using `window.open('login.html', 'new_windwo', '_self');` and it opens a new window, but then there are 2 windows — one where user typed the URL, and the 2nd that we have open in the `onLoad` of the first page.

I am not able to close the first window — `self.close()` and `window.close` aren’t working. I am using Firefox 3.6.

Is there is any way that I can open current page in new window, without creating duplicate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't destroy a window that you didn't create with a script in the first place.

Comment: so without colsing the page can we move that page to fullscreen window?

Comment: No you can't (and I'm really glad that most browsers have an option to stop sites moving windows about). Design your page to work on the web, don't try to adjust the users' software to fit your site.